# Access uploaded file(s) from data component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a quiz web app using Vue and I'd like to use image uploads to make them more visual. When creating a quiz, you can optionally upload an image to each question. The quiz is created on the same page as the questions with questions being created in dialogs. On this 'add quiz' page I would like to be able to edit questions (for instance, see the question I have already 'added' to my quiz and change some details). For this, the image component within each 'edit' dialog would be rendered differently for each question - it will either show an image if one was uploaded or won't. I have no problem uploading images, saving them and pre-viewing them for each new question within an img component. What I have trouble doing is re-accessing already uploaded images without uploading them to my database first.

**How I attempted this:**

Upload a file, pre-view in img tag and save data using:

```
imageAttached(event){
    const files = event.target.files
    this.newQuestionImage = files[0]
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        this.imgsrc = fileReader.result
    })            
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
    this.attachedImages.push({
        question: this.question,
        file: this.newQuestionImage,
        fileURL: this.imgsrc
    })
}
```

I then tried to bind the fileURL to my img component in the 'edit' dialog but this failed. I couldn't think of another way of doing this so I resorted to uploading images to my database after each question has been added and creating a reference to that. An issue here is that this makes adding each question quite cumbersome if e.g. several images are uploaded and it makes editing/deleting a question quite messy so I'd rather have this database upload completed in one simple iterative function when I submit the quiz to be added. Is there a way I can access this file, and others, from a data component and bind it to an img tag?

Comment: Are `this.imgsrc` and `this.attachedImages` both `data` items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `push` inside the event handler so the file value isn't copied before it is set.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    attachedImages: []
  },
  methods: {
    imageAttached(event) {
      const files = event.target.files;
      const fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        this.attachedImages.push({
          question: this.question,
          file: this.newQuestionImage,
          fileURL: fileReader.result
        })
      })
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" @change="imageAttached">
  <img v-for="img in attachedImages" :src="img.fileURL">
</div>
```